# Win32_VideoController returns wrong resolution values in Windows 11

Tags: windows, video, wmic

Executing ***wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution*** at the command line or in a batch file returns ***1920*** and ***1080***, respectively... even though the resolution of my only video adapter (integrated Intel Iris Xe) is set at the Windows-recommended 3840 x 2160.

Any ideas?

Comment: DPI other then 96?

Comment: **Scale** is set to 100%... no idea what that translates to in terms of DPI.  I will mention that it works correctly in Windows 10 at the same resolution and scale, although on another system with an NVIDIA adapter.

Comment: Started working again... nevermind.  :-/